# How to open pdf.js in Firefox via chrome:// URL?

Tags: firefox, pdf, pdf-reader

Firefox components supposedly being accessible by [chrome urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XUL_Tutorial%2FThe_Chrome_URL) (aka. "chrome:// protocol"). How do I open the now built-in pdf.js pdf reader?

I would like to open local pdf files but does **not** want to change my *about:config* settings that are currently set to download pdfs automatically without asking.

**edit** I've tried to enable `pdfjs.disabled` temporarily in order to be able to use some instrospection over a pdf.js opened random pdf file via [dom inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) addon, but I've just recently found this addon (from [Foxy Detective](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxy-detective/)'s [XUL tag](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/tag/xul)) and while I tried to use `File` menu > `inspect chrome document` I still couldn't find a way to see the chrome url for the built-in [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

Comment: Nice link! Now I can enjoy my [recursive browsing session](http://i.stack.imgur.com/akfpO.png). :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call firefox built-in pdf viewer (pdf.js) manually?](http://superuser.com/questions/1152583/how-to-call-firefox-built-in-pdf-viewer-pdf-js-manually).  It's a newer question but has a current answer for people landing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `resource://pdf.js/web/viewer.html` (deduced from bootstrap.js file in PDF Viewer extension but seems to works without the extension too).

There may be problem with opening files, e.g. toolbar button to open file is hidden by default. (Unless you'll figure something out)

Comment: extra thanks for sharing how did you found it out! Now I only will have to forge some css with an [userscript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)!

Comment: +1 This is still a valid answer to this date. For some reason, 'Open File' button doesn't do anything but drag-and-drop PDF file just works fine. Tested in Firefox 50.1.0 on Linux.