# A way to force Firefox to open a file in its Pdf viewer?

Tags: macos, firefox, pdf, firefox-extensions, pdf-reader

I'm trying to view a Pdf file that I found online.

Normally, when I attempt to open a Pdf file, Firefox displays it in its default Pdf viewer (called pdfjs, I believe). This is good and normal behavior.

**However**...
with this specific Pdf that I found online, I click the link to its location, and Firefox brings up the download dialog. It describes the file as a "binary file", even though the file is a Pdf that I can download and view natively.

I'm assuming the web-server is "*not telling*" Firefox that this Pdf file is, in fact, a Pdf file. So Firefox can only assume that it is a "binary file".

This spurred me to wonder the question...

If I were to ever encounter this annoyance again, instead of downloading the file, can I ***force*** Firefox to open a file (online or otherwise) in its default Pdf viewer?

**Attempted Solutions:**

1. I tried the answer from [How to call firefox built-in pdf viewer (pdf.js) manually?](https://superuser.com/questions/1152583/how-to-call-firefox-built-in-pdf-viewer-pdf-js-manually), but to no avail. Firefox just attempts to download the "binary file".
2. I added `view-source:` to the beginning of the Pdf's location (i.e. `view-source:https://www.website.com/pdf.pdf`), I just get the raw ASCII text displayed of the Pdf file.

PS: I'm using Firefox 48.0.2 ...
<sub>Yes, it's old....</sub>

---

**As requested:**

### [image: Screenshot of Response and Request Headers]

Comment: It's possible the website is using the `download` HTML5 attribute. `<a href="document.pdf" download="document.pdf">Download here!</a>`. This will force your browser to save the file instead of opening it like it would normally.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Firefox's inspector shows that it is a regular ```<a href="document.pdf">PDF</a>```.

Comment: There are other ways to force it, like the HTTP Header `content-disposition`. There's a good reason to do this with certain PDFs, like forms or receipts, where you want the user to save the document somewhere appropriate and not in a `temp` folder where files that open in browser are put by default. Anyway, you're asking for solutions and workarounds, but I'm not so sure there will be one.

Comment: @MichaelFrank By the way...This is unrelated to the question but you should change your Profile's website link...It's a spam website that is not appropriate for work

Comment: Ooops. Good catch, that's an old domain.

Comment: Okay, so after looking at your screenshot, it looks like the `content-type: application/octet-stream` is causing your problem. That's basically saying "No idea what this is, just save it." to your browser.

Comment: @MichaelFrank That begs my original question: Can Firefox be forced to open a file in its PdfJs viewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94229/discussion-between-michael-frank-and-i-dont-code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways that sites can force your browser to download a file instead of opening it directly:

## The `download` HTML Attribute

This attribute on an `anchor` tag will attempt to force your browser to download the file instead of processing it in the way it normally would.

Generally this is used when you need to take an automatically generated document name and present it as something nice for the user.

Usage: `<a href="http://www.website.com/path/to/YourDocument.pdf" download="YourDocument.pdf">...`

I have not yet found a way to work around this, but since the real cause of your problem lies below, I haven't researched it entirely...

## HTTP Headers

### `Content-Disposition`

A webserver can respond to a request for a document with the `Content-Disposition` header to describe how the browser should receive the file.

`Content-Disposition: Attachment` will tell the browser that it should download the file, rather than process it as it normally would.

`Content-Disposition: Inline` will tell the browser that it can be displayed inside the webpage, or as the webpage.

Here is a Firefox addon that will take `Attachment` headers and replace them with `Inline` headers:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bypass-forced-download/

Technically, it intercepts `Content-Disposition: attachment` Headers and rewrites them on the fly to `Content-Disposition: inline`. It also allows you to specify websites that should and should-not use this rewrite.

As with most addons, your mileage may vary.

### `Content-Type`

A webserver can respond to a request for a document with the `Content-Type` header to describe the type of document it is returning to the browser.

`Content-Type: application/octet-stream` is defined as "arbitrary binary data" and is basically only downloadable as a file, the browser won't know what to do with it otherwise.

This is what you see when your browser requests the PDF file you are attempting to view.

`Content-Type: application/pdf` is what you would probably need if you wanted to view this file in your browser, or at least have Firefox understand what the file is and how to handle it correctly.

Here is a Firefox addon that can be set to listen for, and rewrite `Content-Type` headers based on their content.

**Note:** [Modifying how your browser handles MIME types can be dangerous.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types#Why_browsers_should_not_guess_MIME_types)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/content-type-fixer/

Again, this addon may or may not work in all cases.

Comment: Although a useful tool, this doesn't seem to solve my particular situation. Could there be another reason why Firefox sees the pdf file as a "binary file" and not a "pdf file? I think that's the issue: Firefox doesn't interpret this ```document.pdf``` file as a Pdf filetype, even though it is.

Comment: Can you open the Inspector and grab the HTTP request/response headers for the download? Add it into your question if you can get it.

Comment: I have them: What specifically should I paste? A picture? Raw text of a certain section?

Comment: The Response Header titled "```Content-Security-Policy```" has "```style-src 'unsafe-inline' github.githubassets.com```".

Comment: You need the `Content-Disposition` header like seen in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUEIJ.png

Comment: There's nothing with that name. ```Conent-Security-Policy``` exists, however. See the image that I attached to my post.